# Applying math to columns where rows hold the same value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes which look like this:

**df1**

```
A       B
AAA     50
BBB     100
CCC     200
```

**df2**

```
C       D
CCC     500
AAA     10
EEE     2100
```

I am trying to output the dataset where column `E` would be `B` - `D` if `A` = `C`. Since `A` values are not aligned with `C` values I cant seem to find the appropriate method to apply calculations and compare the right numbers.

There also are values which are not shared between two datasets in this case I want to add text value 'not found' in those places so that the output would look like this:

**output**

```
A           B           C           D               E
AAA         50          AAA         10              B-D
BBB         100         Not found   Not found       Not found
CCC         200         CCC         500             B-D
Not found   Not found   EEE         2100            Not found
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use outer join with `left_on` and `right_on` parameters with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then subtract columns, for possible subtract numeric is better use missing values:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='A', right_on='C', how='outer')
         .fillna({'A':'Not found', 'C':'Not found'})
         .assign(E = lambda x: x.B - x.D))
print (df)
           A      B          C       D      E
0        AAA   50.0        AAA    10.0   40.0
1        BBB  100.0  Not found     NaN    NaN
2        CCC  200.0        CCC   500.0 -300.0
3  Not found    NaN        EEE  2100.0    NaN
```

Last is possible replace all missing values, only numeric columns are now mixed - strings with numbers, so next processing like some arithmetic operations is problematic:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2, left_on='A', right_on='C', how='outer')
         .assign(E = lambda x: x.B - x.D)
         .fillna('Not found'))
print (df)
           A          B          C          D          E
0        AAA         50        AAA         10         40
1        BBB        100  Not found  Not found  Not found
2        CCC        200        CCC        500       -300
3  Not found  Not found        EEE       2100  Not found
```